# scan .class files or jar file to reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection, jar

In java project, I define a generic class

```
public class Test<T>
```

and a subclass

```
public class SubClass extends Test<Person>
```

My question is how to scan code to find out which class is inherited from the Test, and the type T. As I know, the type T will be erased at runtime.

any method that we can do as that in .net(code as below)？

```
public static void RegisterVadas(Container container, params Assembly[] assemblies)
        {
            assemblies = assemblies.Distinct().ToArray();
            foreach (var assembly in assemblies)
            {
                foreach (var vada in assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(t => t.IsOrHasGenericInterfaceTypeOf(typeof(IVada<>))))
                {
                    RegisterVada(container, vada);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is not possible. Classes are loaded only if they are requested, they are not all available at every time. The bytecode do not check for generic-types, so the T is resolved to Object, generic-variables are always of type Object, to get the content of a generic variable use `.getClass()` on their value.

Comment: @PeterRader he's not asking about any type variable, but about a specific subclass that has a concrete class for that type variable, and that information is recorded in the classfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what do you want to achieve with this?

There are some solutions for this, such as using [Guava's classpath scanner](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/ClassPath.html); you can then find from the class what it's parent class is and what the type parameters are.

Comment: I want to find out all the classes and the type T at runtime which inherits from Test<T>, so I can do something else. meanwhile, this is not useful for debugging model right, since debug cannot produce a jar file?

Comment: You're telling me *how* you want to achieve _something_; it helps to know *why*; sometimes one falls into the [XY problem]*http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the generics type information via reflection:

```
ParameterizedType superType = (ParameterizedType) SubClass.class.getGenericSuperclass();
```

The method allows you to access the type arguments by index. `Test` has only one type argument, so `index == 0` in your case.

```
    /** Get the actual type argument used for a single generic placeholder */
    public <T> Class<T> getGenericType( int index ) {
        Object typeArg = superType.getActualTypeArguments()[ index ];
        if( typeArg instanceof Class ) {
            @SuppressWarnings( JavacWarnings.UNCHECKED )
            Class<T> result = (Class<T>) typeArg;
            return result;
        }

        if( typeArg instanceof ParameterizedType ) {
            ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType) typeArg;
            @SuppressWarnings( JavacWarnings.UNCHECKED )
            Class<T> result = (Class<T>) pt.getRawType();
            return result;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException( "Unsupported type: " + typeArg.getClass() );
    }
```